# Hibernate Many to Many mapping throws javax.persistence.EntityExistsException

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, persistence

I have a many to many relation between Interview and User so I used the Hibernate ManyToMany mapping to make a table. For some reason, even if it says that the PK is: interview_id and user_id => composite key, it throws

```
"javax.persistence.EntityExistsException"
message
:
"A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.company.model.User#usr]"
```

This is how my classes look like:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "interview")
public class Interview {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private int id;

@Column
private String status;

@Column
private String location;

@Column(name = "applicant_id")
private int applicantId;


@Column
private Date start;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "Interview_Emp", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "interview_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_username")})
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>(0);

//getters + setters + equals + hashcode + default constructor
```

And for the user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_t")
public class User {
@Id
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastName;

@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstName;

@Column
private String email;

@Column(name = "phonenumber")
private String phoneNumber;

@Column
private String role;

/*
- tags are separated by | (pipe)
 */
@Column
private String tag;


//getters + setters +equals + hashcode + default constructor
```

When I'm trying to add multiple users to the same interview, I get that error. Any ideas if there's a problem to my annotations?

I tried checking my DAO but I'm only using session.update so I can't change much. Here is my Dao implementation:

```
@Override
public void updateInterview(Interview old,Interview updated) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Interview interviewRes = (Interview)session.get(Interview.class,old.getId());
        interviewRes.setStatus(updated.getStatus());
        interviewRes.setLocation(updated.getLocation());
        interviewRes.setStart(updated.getStart());
        interviewRes.setUsers(updated.getUsers());
        session.update(interviewRes);
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```